# How can I find `deployment menu` in ELK when setting up OIDC authentication

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to setup OIDC authentication on Elasticsearch and Kibana. I am following this instruction: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/oidc-guide-stack.html#oidc-mapping-claims and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-secure-clusters-oidc.html#ec-oidc-client-secret

I can set most of configurations except `client_secret`. In the doc it says in order to set secret I need to open `From your deployment menu, select Security.`. But I don't understand where `deployment menu` is. My elasticsearch service doesn't have any UI and it hasn't connected to Kibana yet. Where can I find the `deployment menu`?

Comment: Are you using ElasticSearch as a Service? The Deployment Menu is part of the elasticsearch as a service only, it is not available if you installed it on-premises or by yourself in any cloud service. Also, do you have a Platinum license? The OpenID Connect is only available with a Platinum license, if you have one the support can guide you through the missing steps.

Comment: I am running Elasticsearch in a docker conatiner. What do you mean by `as a Service`?

Comment: Elasticsearch as a Service is a [managed version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-getting-started.html) where you do not need to deploy, configure and manage it by yourself, you just pay for the instances and use it, like the Elastic Cloud offer from Elastic. Since you are running in a docker, you will not have the `Deployment Menu` you need to follow the first link you posted and you **need** a paid platinum license.